# How to get the positive and negative examples of conjunctions of n literals?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics

So basically, this is an example for conjunction of boolean literals. I do not understand how **n=4** yet it yields an example of **x1 ∧ ¬x2 ∧ x4** which contains only 3 variables.

I also do not understand how we got the positive and negative examples. For example, here **(1, 0, 0, 1)** can be a positive example and **(0, 0, 0, 1)** can be a negative example. Could someone explain please?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n=4$ means that you have four variables, $x_1$ to $x_4$, in total that need to be assigned values. $n$ does not say anything about how many variables will occur in a logical formula (concept). If some of the available variables does not occur in a conjunction, then it means that it is unconstrained and may take any value.

$(1,0,0,1)$ is a positive example for $x_1\land\lnot x_2\land x_4$, because $x_1=1$, $x_2=0$, $x_3=0$ and $x_4=1$ satisfies the formula: $x_1$ is true, $\lnot x_2$ is true (because $x_2=0$), and $x_4$ is true, so all literals are true.

$(0,0,0,1)$ is a negative example for $x_1\land\lnot x_2\land x_4$, because it means $x_1=0$, hence the first literal of the conjunction, $x_1$, is false, hence the whole conjunction.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes sense now.